# CLOSED -- Extjs bind selected combo from view model not work

Tags: javascript, extjs

Hello I've problem to selected by value. And the data is from viewmodel. I also search the answer on google but I not found. I am very confusing about it. Please help me.
This is my form:

```
Ext.define('Sipen.view.items.ItemsForm', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    xtype: 'items-form',

    height: 250,
    width: 500,

    layout: { type: 'fit' },
    bind: {title: '{title}'},

    modal: true,
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'form',
            reference: 'form',
            bodyPadding: 20,
            flex: 1,
            modelValidation: true,
            layout: {
                type: 'hbox',
                align: 'stretch'
            },
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
                    flex: 1,
                    title: 'Item Information',
                    layout: 'anchor',
                    defaults: {
                        anchor: '100%',
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        msgTarget: 'under',
                        labelWidht: 100,
                        allowBlank: false
                    },
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'hiddenfield',
                            name: '_id',
                            bind: '{currentTipe._id}'
                        },
                        {
                            fieldLabel: 'Code',
                            name: 'item_code',
                            bind: '{currentItem.item_code}'
                        },
                        {
                            fieldLabel: 'Name',
                            name: 'item_name',
                            bind: '{currentItem.item_name}'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'numberfield',
                            minValue: 1,
                            fieldLabel: 'Price',
                            name: 'item_price',
                            bind: '{currentItem.item_price}'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'combo',
                            name: 'type',
                            fieldLabel: 'Type',
                            valueField: 'type_name',
                            displayField: 'type_name',
                            queryMode: 'local',
                            forceSelection: true,
                            submitValue: true,
                            bind: {
                                value: '{typeItems.type_name}',
                                store: '{typeItems}',
                                selection: '{currentItem.type_name}'
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            dockedItems: [
                {
                    xtype: 'toolbar',
                    dock: 'bottom',
                    ui: 'footer',
                    layout: {
                        pack: 'end',
                        type: 'hbox'
                    },
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            text: 'Save',
                            formBind: true,
                            listeners: {
                                click: 'onSave'
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            text: 'Cancel',
                            listeners: {
                                click: 'onCancel'
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

Look at xtype 'combo' and I selection data by `{currentItem.type_name}` and the data is right, but I get error

> this Uncaught TypeError: item.getId is not a function.

And this is my view model:

```
Ext.define('Sipen.view.items.ItemsModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.items-items',

    requires: [ 'Sipen.model.Items' ],

    stores: {
        items: {
            model: 'Items',
            autoLoad: true
        },
        typeItems: {
            model: 'TypeItems',
            autoLoad: true
        }
    }
});
```

Sorry for my bad english, but please help me...

**============[Fixed]======================**

I've found the result in here https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?302067

So the script should be like this:

```
{
    xtype: 'combo',
    name: 'type',
    fieldLabel: 'Type',
    valueField: 'type_name',
    displayField: 'type_name',
    queryMode: 'local',
    forceSelection: true,
    submitValue: true,
    bind: {
        value: '{typeItems.type_name}',
        store: '{typeItems}',
        selection: '{currentItem.type_name}'
    }
}
```

Comment: can you create a [fiddle](http://fiddle.sencha.com)?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @aviram83 but I am not know to create fiddle with sencha. Sorry I'am new using sencha.